# Selenium executeScript won't return array of elements

Tags: javascript, selenium, testing

I'm new to Selenium and trying to wrap my head around it. I'm trying some lines of JS in the Chrome console and if they work, execute them via `executeScript`.

I'm doing for example: `document.swQuerySelectorAll("[fill]");`

In Chrome, this will return the following:

[image]

E.g. an array of 4 `path`s.

Doing the same in Selenium:

```
async getWithFill(){
  return this.driver.executeScript("return document.swQuerySelectorAll('[fill]')");
}

...
...

const withfill = await this.getWithFill();
console.log("withfill: " + JSON.stringify(withfill, getCircularReplacer()));
```

(`getCircularReplacer` as per [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Cyclic_object_value))

This, however, won't return n array of paths, but this, which looks like it's the `driver` object itself:

```
[{"driver_":{"flow_":{"propagateUnhandledRejections_":true,"activeQueue_":null,"taskQueues_":{},"shutdownTask_":null,"hold_":{"_called":false,"_idleTimeout":2147483647,"_idlePrev":{"_unrefed":false,"msecs":2147483647,"_timer":{}},"_idleStart":40995,"_repeat":2147483647,"_destroyed":false}},"session_":{"stack_":null,"parent_":null,"callbacks_":null,"state_":"fulfilled","handled_":true,"value_":"e4e6a8fe5fda07f3f72c0cbf328ed68d","queue_":{"name_":"TaskQueue::14","tasks_":[],"interrupts_":null,"pending_":null,"subQ_":null,"state_":"finished","unhandledRejections_":{}}},"executor_":{"w3c":false,"customCommands_":{},"log_":{"name_":"webdriver.http.Executor","level_":null,"parent_":{"name_":"webdriver.http","level_":null,"parent_":{"name_":"webdriver","level_":null,"parent_":{"name_":"","level_":{"name_":"OFF","value_":null},"parent_":null,"handlers_":null},"handlers_":null},"handlers_":null},"handlers_":null}},"fileDetector_":null},"id_":{"stack_":null,"parent_":null,"callbacks_":null,"state_":"fulfilled","handled_":false,"value_":"0.5320635799241777-7","queue_":{"name_":"TaskQueue::1680","tasks_":[],"interrupts_":null,"pending_":null,"subQ_":null,"state_":"finished","unhandledRejections_":{}}}},{"id_":{"stack_":null,"parent_":null,"callbacks_":null,"state_":"fulfilled","handled_":false,"value_":"0.5320635799241777-8"}}]
```

What even is this and how do I get an array of `path`s to return as expected based on the Chrome console output?

Comment: Is there some reason you aren't running `driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("[fill]"))` and dealing with the return using "normal" Selenium instead of using JSE? What you are printing is not related to your `getWithFill()` call. You store `withfill` but never use it... at least in the code you posted.

Comment: I don't know what JSE is, I'm just trying to use the tests the same way my colleagues did. Sorry, that was a typo, `withfill` is actually what I'm printing (updated code - forgot to rename it).

Comment: JSE is `JavaScriptExecutor`. What is it that you expect to be printed to the console? `withfill` is going to contain a collection of WebElements, not simple objects.

Comment: I'd be happy if it contained WebElements, instead it has the `driver` object I marked as "mess" in my question.

Comment: Anyway, point of the question is: why does it not return the same as the Chrome console, and how to make it so that it does?

Comment: It doesn't return the same because you aren't calling the same code in both places. In the console you are running, `document.swQuerySelectorAll("[fill]")`. In your code, you have nested that call inside a `JSON.stringify()` call. You still haven't answered the question... what do you expect it to print?

Comment: I did answer the question: `return the same as the Chrome console `. E.g. an array of `path`s. I don't understand why a `document.swQuerySelectorAll("[fill]")` would be different when stored and when printed to the console.

Comment: What's printed to the console is prettified. That's not what's actually returned because a collection of objects are returned. If you want to see what's actually the equivalent (or close to it), do `console.log("withfill: " + withfill);`.

Comment: I really don't mind if it's prettified or not. `console.log("withfill: " + withfill);` prints `[object Object],[object Object]`. Prettified or not, it should contain `path`s, not the `driver:` stuff that it does. I don't understand what I'm not clear about.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186801/discussion-between-lte-and-jeffc).